# In proof-of-stake, What is the "hash value" parameter in randomized-block-selection

Tags: proof-of-stake

So I'm researching the proof of stake consensus protocol, and one fundamental aspect in proof of stake for electing forger nodes is **randomized block selection**.

From my research, randomized block selection selects a node based on the lowest "hash value" combined with the highest stake.

My question is what does this "hash value" represent? I can't seem to find anywhere what is being hashed specifically. Is it just the hash of the blocks data? Because if so then another question arises where if the network looks for the lowest block hash value, then how is this saving any energy since nodes will still mine for a low block hash to increase selection chance.

Answer (score 0):

So from what I understand you're not studying ethereum. It would help to have a reference of what you are looking at to understand what is indeed the hash value you're speaking of.
From what I've seen so far the hash value would rather be the hash of the proposer's public key plus some variable like the height of the block.

[Algorand](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.01341.pdf) has a fascinating way of choosing  a block proposer (or leader) that may be of interest to you (sort of related to what I've said).

Comment: I see, this makes sense. So it can vary based on each implementation. In your case (hashing proposers pubkey + variable like blockheight), do you mean the public key address or the original public key used to derive the address? And yeah. Will certainly look into algorand soon

Comment: In my case it was a made up scenario, I was trying to simplify it. Usually you use some crypto magic to sign with your private key some value, here block height, for instance, and everyone can tell that you actually did it without you revealing your private key, this way no one can predict your result before you.
An other lead for your research would be single secret leader election (SSLE) (see https://ethresear.ch/t/simplified-ssle/12315).